# How to limit EF Core command text logging via Serilog

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, serilog

How do I limit the commandText size when using EFCore logging with Serilog? (And Serilog MS logging extensions.)

Comment: I don't have control of EFCore logging classes, so [Destructurama.Attributed](https://nblumhardt.com/2014/07/using-attributes-to-control-destructuring-in-serilog/#destructuring-with-attributes) is no help.

Answer (score 0):

**Program.cs**

```
int commandTextMaxLength = 300;
IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
    .ReadFrom.Services(services)
    .Destructure.ByTransforming<CommandEventData>(
        logData => logData.Command?.CommandText?.Length > commandTextMaxLength ? 
            new {
                //logData.Connection,
                Command = new
                {
                    IsTrucated = true,
                    CommandText = logData.Command.CommandText.Substring(0, commandTextMaxLength) + "...",
                    logData.Command.CommandTimeout,
                    logData.Command.CommandType,
                    logData.Command.Parameters,
                    //logData.Command.Site
                    //logData.Command.UpdatedRowSource
                },
                logData.Context,
                logData.ExecuteMethod,
                logData.CommandId,
                logData.ConnectionId,
                logData.IsAsync,
                logParameterValues=false,
                logData.StartTime,
                logData.CommandSource
            }
            : logData)
// optional .Enrich.FromLogContext()
// optional .Enrich.WithProcessId()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .ConfigureLogging(builder => builder.AddSerilog())
;
```

Comment: Leaving this answer just to demonstrate IDestructurePolicy is a lot simpler than new {} the whole structure of `CommandEventData`.

Answer (score 0):

**EntityFrameworkCoreCommandTextDestructurePolicy.cs**

```cs
// in Program.cs
// .Destructure.With<EntityFrameworkCoreCommandTextDestructurePolicy>()

public class EntityFrameworkCoreCommandTextDestructurePolicy : Serilog.Core.IDestructuringPolicy
{
    public static int MaxSqlText { get; set; } = 300;

    public bool TryDestructure(
        object value
        , Serilog.Core.ILogEventPropertyValueFactory propertyValueFactory
        , out Serilog.Events.LogEventPropertyValue result
        )
    {
        if (value is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.CommandEventData d && d.Command?.CommandText?.Length > MaxSqlText)
        {
            var newObj = new {
                Command = new {
                    CommandText = d.Command.CommandText = d.Command.CommandText.Substring(0, MaxSqlText) + "..."
                }
            };
            result = propertyValueFactory.CreatePropertyValue(newObj, destructureObjects: true);
            return true;
        }

        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why separate answer? Update the existing one.

Comment: @GuruStron In case some readers think `.ByTransforming()` would be simpler (it is for low property counts and non-nesting).  FWIW - I thought it might be.

Comment: No need to post a separate answer. Please update existing one mentioning this as alternative.

Comment: @GuruStron Can you provide a link that says two answers from the same person should be combined?  I ask because I am a big believer in StackOverflow "long tail" and I'd prefer I be able to delete an answer if I figure out later it is bad.  I'd also like readers to be able to vote on each alternative separately.